# jquery validating text entered with comma

Tags: jquery

I have the below to check if the text entered has a comma.

```
$("#keywords").change(function() {
    if (this.value.indexOf(",") == -1) {
        alert('Please separate multiple keywords with a comma.');
    }
});
```

I basically want a way to tell the user if he is entering more than one word without a comma, he needs to separate it with a comma. The above change event seems to trigger everytime. I am sure there is a better event to do this. Can any one please suggest. thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just validate the input when the user submits the data:

```js
$('#warningMessage').hide()
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  $('#value').each(function() {
    if (($.trim($(this).val()).indexOf(",") == -1)) {
      //alert('Please separate multiple keywords with a comma.');
      $('#warningMessage').show();
    } else {
      $('#warningMessage').hide()
    }
  });
  if (isValid == false) e.preventDefault();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label">Value</div>
<input type="text" id="value" name="value" />
<br />
<div style="margin-left:140px;">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</div>
<div style="color:orange;" id="warningMessage"><b>Please separate multiple keywords with a comma</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to show the message right under the text box after hitting submit? thanks

Comment: I have changed my post to display an error message in orange if there is no comma in the input.

Comment: @Alex its incorrect not working because if here if i have only one value like 1 then i am getting error Please separate multiple keywords with a comma it should not give error for single value.

Answer (score 4):

Check if user has entered more than one word i.e. if the value contains space, then show the message.

```
if(this.value.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
```

---

I'd recommend you to use `pattern` on the input as follow.

```
[a-zA-Z]+(,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

[**Regex online Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/gN4aG6/1)

1. `[a-zA-Z]+`: Allow one or more alphabets, both lowerCase and upperCase
2. `(,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*`: Allow zero or more of the string that starts with comma separated by optional space and then one or more alphabets.

```css
span {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
input:invalid {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
input:invalid ~ span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="keywords" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(,\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*" /><span>Keywords should be separated by comma</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Event as **onchange** is ok to do this. The other thing is what if user writes only one keyword - should it alert him then?

Add check for spaces - if there aren't any dont show message (one keyword).

Comment: No, only if one keyword is entered no alert needs to be shown, how should i check for spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQuery validator then you can register a custom validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkComma", function(value, element) {
        var words = value.split(" ").length;
        var commas = value.split(",").length;
        // For n number of comma, there must be n + 1 spaces i.e. words
        return words === (commas + 1)
    },
    "Please separate multiple keywords with a comma."
);
```

Now, in your input field, add this validator:

```
<input type="text" name="myname" check-comma="" />
```

Or you can use the same logic as you are using:

```
$("#keywords").change(function() {
    var words = value.split(" ").length;
    var commas = value.split(",").length;
    // For n number of comma, there must be n + 1 spaces i.e. words
    if (words != (commas + 1)) {
        alert('Please separate multiple keywords with a comma.');
    }
});
```