# Form Validation in Html & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate my form with this javascript code, but this code firing the alert in case of any wrong input is entered, but my colleague says there should not be any alert. He says message should be show in front of textfield like below image. can anyone help me, How is it possible ?

[image]

My javascript and html code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(form.username.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
      alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
      if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
        alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
        alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[0-9]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[a-z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[A-Z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
      form.pwd1.focus();
      return false;
    }

    alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
    return true;
  }

</script>

<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p>
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33500623/2025923), use `pattern`.

Comment: Try using spring MVC it could sort ou your issue or else if you want to do in same use ajax

Comment: Alerts are annoying, especially in case of the user couldn't match like 3 conditions of your situation, instead use a list `li` or div or span and throw all errors all at once inside that div, ALSO consider this check is just a visual check on the client side, and you MUST check on the server-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `alert()`, you should write your own message display function. First, you need to add that error message container element in your html:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
  <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
  <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p>
  <p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
  <p id="error-message-container" color="red"></p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

And in Javascript part, you need to define an error display method which displays this error text inside `error-message-container` element:

```
function displayError(msg){
  document.getElementById('error-message-container').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Now you are ready to use `displayError` function instead of `alert()`, wherever you want to show an error like:

```
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
  displayError("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
  form.username.focus();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to insert a blank DIV after each input, and your javascript will insert error messages into them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(form.username.value == "") {
      document.getElementById("username_error").innerHTML=("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
      document.getElementById("username_error").innerHTML=("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
      if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
        document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[0-9]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[a-z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[A-Z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
      form.pwd1.focus();
      return false;
    }

    document.getElementById("pwd1_error").innerHTML=("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
    return true;
  }

</script>

<form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"><div id="username_error"></div></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"><div id="pwd1_error"></div></p>
<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest JQuery validation plugin:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Demo:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/